# How to make Jcoverflip Loop?

Tags: jquery

I searched and found questions similar to my question, however none has the specific solution I need. I currently have Jcoverflip without the scroll bar or any next/prev buttons... what I would like to accomplish is... on hover, have the gallery scroll and when it reaches to the end it loops instead of having scroll all the way backwards. I'm currently new to javascript/Jquery and would appreciate any help..also if you have any alternative scripts in mind, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that Jcoverflip does provide this functionality out of the box. One thing, that came in my mind, was to try to bind to the change event and appending the first item to the list like this:

```
$('#flip').jcoverflip({
  ...
  change: function(){ $('#flip li:first').appendTo('#flip'); },
  ...
});
```

I did not try out this code, but it may work depending on Jcoverflips implementation.

Comment: Thank you for helping... unfortunately it didn't work... I'm starting to think it would be easier for me to look for another script...do you know any with similar functionality?